# How to combine Google Apps SPF & Campaign Monitor SPF?

Tags: dns, spf

I'm trying to combine two SPFs into one, namely a Google Apps and Campaign Monitor SPF.

Is there any possible way to do this?

E.g.

```
SPF A:
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all

SPF B:
v=spf1 mx include:cmail1.com ~all
```

What is A + B ?

Answer (score 15):

Let's break it down:

```
v=spf1
```

Just says the version of SPF being used and that this is an SPF record.

```
include:_spf.google.com
```

Parse the SPF rules on _spf.google.com (i.e. if the source would pass against _spf.google.com, then it will pass against your site)

```
~all
```

Soft fail if none of these rules are matched (-all would be a hard fail, which people generally avoid when setting up Google Mail on their domain)

```
mx
```

Allow the source IP to send as the domain in question if the source IP is present as an MX record on the domain.

```
include:cmail1.com
```

Another include, this time against cmail1.com

Final result:

```
v=spf1 mx include:_spf.google.com include:cmail1.com ~all
```

I used the [SPF syntax page](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax) to put this all together.